# How can I create a MySQL query to include all of this information?

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli, odbc

I am creating a report and I need to be able to create a query(s) to pull the information below into a report. Essentially here's what I want listed:

> ```
>    ship.name
>    personnel.first_name
>    personnel.last_name
>    crew_position_title.title
>    personnel_next_of_kin.next_of_kin_relation
>    personnel_next_of_kin.next_of_kin_first_name
>    personnel_next_of_kin.next_of_kin_last_name
>    personnel_next_of_kin.next_of_kin_telephone
>    personnel_next_of_kin.next_of_kin_alt_telephone
>    personnel_next_of_kin.other_kin_relation
>    personnel_next_of_kin.other_kin_first_name
>    personnel_next_of_kin.other_kind_last_name
>    personnel_next_of_kin.other_kin_telephone
>    personnel_next_of_kin.other_kin_alt_telephone
> ```

The only condition would be `WHERE personnel.currently_serving_ship_id IS NOT NULL` on the personnel table.

How would I go about creating a query to give me the data I need? I have tried using JOIN but I don't have much experience with them.

Below is the ERD of the tables I need data from with fields of interest highlighted:

[image: database_erd]

Comment: What did your `JOIN` attempt look like?

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM personnel 
LEFT OUTER JOIN personnel_next_of_kin 
ON personnel.personnel_id = personnel_next_of_kin.personnel_id 
WHERE personnel.currently_serving_ship_id IS NOT NULL LIMIT 100;

I don't want to use SELECT * as that pulls in all the fields. This query doesn't include the crew_position_title.title however

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like?

```
SELECT s.name, p.first_name, p.last_name, c.title, pnk.next_of_kin_relation,
                pnk.next_of_kin_first_name, pnk.next_of_kin_last_name, pnk.next_of_kin_telephone,
                pnk.next_of_kin_alt_telephone, pnk.other_kin_relation, pnk.other_kin_first_name, 
                pnk.other_kin_last_name, pnk.other_kin_telephone, pnk.other_kin_alt_telephone
            FROM personnel p
                LEFT JOIN personnel_next_of_kin pnk ON pnk.personnel_id = p.personnel_id
                LEFT JOIN ship s ON s.ship_id = p.currently_serving_ship_id
                LEFT JOIN personnel_key_info pk ON pk.personnel_id = p.personnel_id
                LEFT JOIN crew_position_title c ON c.crew_pos_id = p.personnel_id
            WHERE p.currently_serving_ship_id IS NOT NULL
```

This is the long version of the query. I am not really sure about this: LEFT JOIN crew_position_title c ON c.crew_pos_id = p.personnel_id. I can't tell what key should be used there, can't figure out using the naming convention.

Query was not tested but you can give it a shot and fix the syntax issue if there are any.

Comment: Wow, that was a pretty quick and accurate response! The only syntax errors were typos. I'd comment with the typos fixed but the query exceeds comment length limit. THANKS!